# Dynamically allocated object producer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

Look at this class:

```
//HPP
class A {
  public:
    A();
    ~A();
    B *fetchNew();

  private:
    B *currentValue;
}


//CPP
A::A() {}

A::~A {
   delete currentValue;
}

B *A::fetchNew() {
    delete currentValue;
    currentValue = new B();
    //apply magic to currentValue
    return currentValue;
}
```

This class holds a pointer to instance of class B. Every time `fetchNew()` is called, the old one gets deleted, a new one is allocated and magic is applied to it, after what new and shiny `currentValue` is returned.

This method is called very frequently (in real life, it's a method that returns a view matrix in a game's main loop, so it's called once every frame, about 60 times a second).

Once the A object gets deleted, it deletes the current `currentValue`, which would otherwise leak.

Is there a prettier way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Here's the actual code, since it has a twist (just the `fetchNow()` method):

```
glm::mat4x4 *Camera::getViewMatrix() {
    //transformation <<-apply shiny and fancy magic;

    delete viewMatrix;
    viewMatrix = new glm::mat4x4();
    *viewMatrix *= glm::mat4_cast(transformation->getRotation());
    *viewMatrix = glm::translate(*viewMatrix, transformation->getPosition());

    return viewMatrix;
}
```

Comment: You should rather use a `std::unique_ptr<B>` as result of `fetchNew()`

Comment: I have a function call that look like this: `B *translate(B *toTranslate, int translateAmount)`. How do I deal with that? `std::make_unique`?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the context. Does that function creat a new instance of `B`?

Comment: I added the code to the question. Edit: And fixed it.

Comment: As for your edit: You can use the dereferencing operator of `std::unique_ptr` as with any raw pointer.

Comment: I know, but how do I assign the new value to the pointer while passing the old value to the function in the final line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a prettier way to achieve this?

I would recommend rather to use a **`std::unique_ptr<B>`** than a raw pointer `B*`:

```
//HPP
#include <memory>
class A {
  public:
    A();
    ~A();
    std::unique_pty<B> fetchNew();

  private:
    // You don't need that: B *currentValue;
}
```

---

```
//CPP
A::A() {}

A::~A {
   // You don't need that: delete currentValue;
}

std::unique_ptr<B> A::fetchNew() {
    // You don't need that: delete currentValue;
    std::unique_ptr<B> newValue = std::make_unique<B>();
    // apply magic to newValue and dereference using * or -> as with any raw pointer
    return newValue;
}
```

---

This approach has several advantages:

- You don't have to care about deletion or memory leaks in `A`
- The transfer of ownership for the result of `fetchNew()` is semantically clear
- It's a more clear API, the client will know they get ownership of the pointer and do not have to riddle if they need to delete that instance or not
- You give the client the flexibility to determine the lifetime scope of the `B` instance themselves.

---

As for your edited addition it should look like:

```
std::unique_ptr<glm::mat4x4> Camera::getViewMatrix() {
    //transformation <<-apply shiny and fancy magic;

    std::unique_ptr<glm::mat4x4> viewMatrix = std::make_unique<glm::mat4x4>();
    *viewMatrix *= glm::mat4_cast(transformation->getRotation());
    *viewMatrix = glm::translate(*viewMatrix, transformation->getPosition());

    return viewMatrix;
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to be applicable to the code in the edit? The last line before the return statement is a bit tricky.

Comment: I was messing up make_unique and unique_ptr and things... Ehh, still new to this, but this made it a lot more clear. Thanks!